# When meta-knight grabs you, is there a button you can push to avoid damage?

Tags: kirby-and-the-forgotten-land

In Kirby and the Forgotten land, in the meta-knight colesseum fight, there's a part in the second phase where Meta-Knight can pick you up and start attacking you. The camera zooms in and there about 10 attacks. None of them seem blockable, you can't move/dodge, and I tried spamming "B" but it doesn't do anything. It takes about 1/4th of your health.

[image]

Is there any way to avoid damage, or is this just a "you should have dodged earlier" moment?

Comment: Are you talking about the move Upper Calibur, like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p34RYVS9qyo (skip to 3:20 for the Meta Knight fight in Forgotten Land)